# Socket.io server is receiving only the first event out of multiple event emit from client

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express, server, socket.io

I am creating a react that with the functionality for realtime sharing of data and I'm using `socket.io` and `express` for backend and `socket.io-client` to emit event from the client to the backend

I have some data to send to the backend on page load, but when I emit the events from the client with the data and listen to them in the backend, only data for the first emmited event is gotten in the backend when logged to the `console`

Here is my frontend code emmiting the events

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import reactLogo from "./assets/react.svg";
import viteLogo from "/vite.svg";
import "./App.css";
import io from "socket.io-client";

const PORT = "http://localhost:3000";
const connectionOptions = {
  "force new connection": true,
  reconnectionAttempts: "Infinity",
  timeout: 10000,
  retries: 3,
  transport: ["websocket"],
};

const server = io(PORT, connectionOptions);

function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    server.emit("start");
    server.emit("end");
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <a href="https://vitejs.dev" target="_blank">
          <img src={viteLogo} className="logo" alt="Vite logo" />
        </a>
        <a href="https://react.dev" target="_blank">
          <img src={reactLogo} className="logo react" alt="React logo" />
        </a>
      </div>
      <h1>Vite + React</h1>
      <div className="card">
        <button onClick={() => setCount((count) => count + 1)}>
          count is {count}
        </button>
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.jsx</code> and save to test HMR
        </p>
      </div>
      <p className="read-the-docs">
        Click on the Vite and React logos to learn more
      </p>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is my backend code listening to the events

```
import express from "express";
import http from "http";
import { Server } from "socket.io";
import cors from "cors";

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = new Server(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "*",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
  },
});

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("Connected");

  socket.on("start", () => {
    console.log("start");
  });

  socket.on("end", () => {
    console.log("end");
  });

  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log("Disconnected");
  });
});

server.listen(port, () =>
  console.log(`server is running on http://localhost:${port}`)
);

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("MathCollab server");
});
```

On load of my webpage I expect to see the following logs in my backend console

```
Connected
start
end
```

but all I'm seeing in my console is

```
Connected
start
```

What am I neglecting in the code

Comment: it seems that removing `retries` in the `connectionOptions ` makes it work. I have no idea why so i'll keep it as a comment here.

Comment: @LãNgọcHải removing retries does really make it work, but won't that affect something else

Answer (score 0):

It could be because of the way you are emitting events from the client. It's likely that the events are getting emitted asynchronously and since start and end events are getting emitted almost simultaneously, there's a race condition happening where only one of them is being received properly on the server side.
So instead of relying on timing, you could ensure that the start event is emitted only after the end event is acknowledged. One way to achieve this would be to utilize acknowledgments in Socket.IO.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  server.emit("start", () => {
    // acknowledgment callback for start event
    server.emit("end"); // Emit end event after start event is acknowledged
  });
}, [])
```

And get your server-side code to send acknowledgments,

```js
socket.on("start", (callback) => {
  console.log("start");
  callback(); // Acknowledge start event
});

socket.on("end", () => {
  console.log("end");
});
```

This approach will ensure that the end event will only be emitted after the start event is acknowledged by the server, ensuring the sequential order of events.
Removing the retries option might have resolved the issue because it possibly altered the timing of the event emissions, making them more sequential rather than simultaneous.